# How can i filter and modify each object in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, trim

I'm developing a little webapp which receives an array of objects from an api and then shows the result on the page after adding some data to each object and deleting other objects.

I have tried by chechink if the current index element is the same as the nexts but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
const initialArray = [
{ x: 'one', y: 'place1'},
{ x: 'one', y: 'place1'},
{ x: 'two', y: 'place2'},
{ x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
{ x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
{ x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
{ x: 'four', y: 'place4'}
]
```

The expected result should be:

```
let resArray = [
{ x: 'one' , y: 'place1', count: 2},
{ x: 'two', y: 'place2', count: 1 },
{ x: 'three', y: 'place3', count: 3 },
{ x: 'four', y: 'place4', count: 1 }
]
```

console doesn't give any error so it means my algorithm was incorrect.
Thanks for the support

Comment: please provide also the actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()`

```js
const initialArray = [
  { x: 'one', y: 'place1'},
  { x: 'one', y: 'place1'},
  { x: 'two', y: 'place2'},
  { x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
  { x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
  { x: 'three', y: 'place3'},
  { x: 'four', y: 'place4'}
];

const res = initialArray.reduce((ac,{x,y}) => {
  let k = `${x}_${y}`
  if(!ac[k]) ac[k] = {x,y,count:0};
  ac[k].count++;
  return ac;


},{})
console.log(Object.values(res))
```